# PHP mail() sending only to single recipient

Tags: php, email

I was updating few non PHP related pages for the client which send form input over to PHP. However without making any changes to the code client reported to not getting the e-mails. Instead he said it only sends emails to one of the emails instead of all 3. Can some one pin point whats wrong with the code?

```
$email_to = "info@example.com, user@live.ca, user@live.ca"; 

    $email_subject = "VIP Access"."  [".date("Y-m-d @ h:m:s A")."]";

    $first_name   = $_POST["objFirstName"];
    $last_name = $_POST["objLastName"];
    $phone     = $_POST["objPhone"];
    $email_from = $_POST["objEmail"];

    $full_name = $first_name."&nbsp;".$last_name;

    $message = "";

      function clean_string($string) {
        $bad = array("content-type", "bcc:", "to:", "cc:", "href");
        return str_replace($bad, "", $string);
      }


    $message .= "<html><body>\n";
    $message .= "<table rules='all' border='1' style='border-color:#000;' cellpadding='10' width='100%'>\n";
    $message .= "<tr style='background: #eee;'><td width='20%'><strong>Full Name:</strong> </td><td width='70%'>".clean_string($full_name)."</td></tr>\n";
    $message .= "<tr style='background: #eee;'><td width='20%'><strong>Email:</strong> </td><td width='70%'>".clean_string($email_from)."</td></tr>\n";
    $message .= "<tr style='background: #eee;'><td width='20%'><strong>Phone:</strong> </td><td width='70%'><a href='tel:".clean_string($phone)."'>".clean_string($phone)."</a></td></tr>\n";
    $message .= "</table>\n";
    $message .= "<img src='http://example.com/images/logo-trans.png' width='120' height='130' alt='Estate Brothers' style='text-align:center;'/>\n";
    $message .= "</body></html>\n";

    // create email headers
    $headers = "From: ".$email_from." via example.com\r\n"."Reply-To: ".$email_from."\r\n"."X-Mailer: PHP/".phpversion()."via example.com";
    $headers .= 'To: Example <info@example.com>, User <user@live.ca>, User two <usertwo@live.ca>' . "\r\n";
    $headers .= 'MIME-Version: 1.0'."\r\n";
    $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1'."\r\n";

    $mail_feed =  mail($email_to, $email_subject, $message, $headers);
```

Comment: @Prix That won't make a difference. Both will still be strings.

Comment: Editing a small error which might interfere with the headers.

Comment: What should your `clean_string` do? Why do you remove those strings?

Comment: @Prix use of " or ' wont make any difference. But thanks.

Comment: @kelunik The code is not written by me, but I am not getting paid to rewrite it to something proper. Customer said as long as it works somewhat there happy.

Comment: You missed a `.` near the headers it overwrote itself. Also added in To: headers. See if it works.

And I also recommend to not use two the same E-mailadresses in a mail function I don't think it allows that. Not sure if you have that in the live version of the site but it's a heads up.

Comment: @TomKriek Thanks Tom. See the odd part the script works as above from my own servers. But it worked fine for the client as well. There just not getting e-mails to there Live accounts while I was testing it I got e-mail to my Hotmail without issues.

Comment: Check your server for blacklisting.
http://mxtoolbox.com/

Comment: @TomKriek there using GoDaddy for hosting. I would expect issues.

Comment: Is it a possibility to implement a different method of mailing? Like swiftmailer?

I can provide a small snippet to easily use it.

Comment: @TomKriek That would be awesome, I was considering moving them to Swiftmailer.

Comment: @MemeCat Alright I'll prepare the snippet and post it as an answer.
The `mail()` function can be real tricky sometimes.

Comment: @TomKriek being honest I think mail() has been broken for quite some time. Its hard to get PHP mails to be marked as non-spam and in general its seems to be such a pain in the ass to make work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acquite swiftmailer here -> http://swiftmailer.org/

```
require_once 'swiftmailer/lib/swift_required.php';

function new_mail($subject, $content)
{
    // Create the message
    $message = Swift_Message::newInstance();

    // Give the message a subject
    $message->setSubject($subject);

    // Set the From address with an associative array
    $message->setFrom(array('sender@example.com' => 'Sender')));

    // Set the To addresses with an associative array
    $message->setTo(array('info@example.com' => 'Example'));

    // Give it a body
    $message->setBody($content);

    $transport = Swift_MailTransport::newInstance();
    $mailer = Swift_Mailer::newInstance($transport);
    $result = $mailer->send($message);

}

new_mail('Subject', $messagecontentgoeshere);
```

If you want you can replace the TO and FROM parts with variables as well. So you can reuse the whole function everywhere on the site.

Comment: It's not a real answer but an alternative so I don't know if it's appropriate to mark it as one. But glad I could help.

Comment: It is alternative, but its a good alternative answer since everyone knows mail() has issues.

Comment: Haven't used swiftmailer before but seems pretty interesting. +1 for sharing.

Answer (score 0):

Try these things:

1. Remove all spaces in the email_to variable (I know the RFC states spaces are allowed but some people ran into issues and removing the spaces fixes it for them):

   ```
   $email_to = 'info@example.com,user@live.ca,user@live.ca';
   ```
2. Insure you escape all your `$_POST` variable to avoid injections.
3. You can do the TO using the headers as opposed to using mail to (notice concatenation fix like the other answers spoke about):

   ```
   $email_to = "info@example.com";
   ....
   $headers = "From: ".$email_from." via example.com\r\n"."Reply-To: ".$email_from."\r\n"."X-Mailer: PHP/".phpversion()."via example.com\r\n";
   $headers  .= 'To: user@live.ca, user@live.ca'."\r\n";
   $headers  .= 'MIME-Version: 1.0'."\r\n";
   $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1'."\r\n";
   ```
4. Another solution would be to send the email multiple times (insure you have the other fixes in for the headers including the missing \r\n for x-mailer):

   ```
   $email_to = array('info@example.com', 'user@live.ca', 'user@live.ca');
   ....
   $mail_feed = true;
   foreach ($email_to as $email) {
       $mail_feed =  $mail_feed && mail($email, $email_subject, $message, $headers);
   }
   ```

Comment: There is no DB end to this, it sends form data directly to the e-mail.

Comment: Yes, and injections are also a problems with emails not just DB: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_injection.

Comment: Huh interesting. Thanks for pointing that out personally was not aware of that. I knew about SQL. But not plain mail.

Comment: @MemeCat a book I once read said. **All foreign user input is tainted, unless it has been cleansed by programming.** I always heed this sentence when working with input and output.